# Data not getting store in database using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

This is a student registration form from where student can register and data will be store in database, but these values are not stored in database.

my JDBC code through this i m getting the form values to store in database.. But this is not stored in database. Help me out from this prob this is very annoying error as there is no error in program but the values is also not stored in database ...

```
try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");           
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",
                                               "system",
                                               "nisha");
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into student5 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1,fname);
    ps.setString(2,lname);
    ps.setString(3,gen);
    ps.setString(4,add);
    ps.setString(5,city);
    ps.setString(6,state);
    ps.setString(7,pin); 
    ps.setString(8,email); 

    // ps.setString(8,markt);
    ps.setString(9,pass); 
    // ps.setString(10,marko); 
    ps.setString(10,emp); 
    ps.setString(11,skil);
    ps.setString(12,pac);
    ps.setString(13,rol);

    int i=ps.executeUpdate();
    if(i>0){
        System.out.print("Student added successfully");
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("Unable to add Student!");
    }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CReg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Help will be appreciated

Comment: You have to `commit()` the database transaction.

Comment: I thing jdbc-oracle.jar is missing web-inf/lib folder, please check it also check logs

Comment: It'd help if you could format the code properly and add a full working example!

Comment: @localghost He hasn't disabled auto-commit, so he doesn't need to call commit (and if he would, it would throw an exception).